# How can I compile and run my Pascal code in VS code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can modify tasks.json and keybingings to create shortcuts for compiling the code and running it?
After a ton of googling I came up with this. When I press ctrl+shift+b it compiles but command prompt with the program doesn't pop up.

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "cmd",
"args": ["/C"],
"tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Compile",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["\"fpc ${file}\""]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Run",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["\"start $[fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\""]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `start $[` looks like a typo. Did you mean `start ${`?

Comment: Pascal?.....but, why?

Comment: I dont think you need `"isBuildCommand": true` for Run

Comment: Yes it was a typo, fixing it didn't change anything.

Comment: I don't personally use it it is for school, lol.

Comment: I tried both completely removing "isBuildCommand": true and settiing it to false, doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @ChenGuevara Take a look here: http://blog.omnipascal.com/how-to-attach-the-build-process-to-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 8):

Pascal is stil alive and kicking. What I meant by Pascal is the modern object Pascal programming, not your daddy's Pascal. I've been making many apps for all platforms using (mainly) [Free Pascal](http://freepascal.org), with [Lazarus IDE](http://lazarus-ide.org) (for GUI apps) and VS Code (for non-GUI apps). Modern Pascal can do whatever every other languages out there are able to do. Check out [The Big 5 Pascal of Today](http://pak.lebah.web.id/pascal5.html).

Now… to be able to work use Pascal with VS Code. First, install Free Pascal for sure. Then install the [OmniPascal](http://omnipascal.com) extension. And read my guide [Free Pascal and VS Code](https://paklebah.github.io/fpc-dan-vscode.html). I provide many useful tasks in there to help you work with Pascal, including code formatting. It's in Indonesian but you could use Google Translate to [read it in English](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=id&sl=id&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fpaklebah.github.io%2Ffpc-dan-vscode.html) (or whatever language you like).

HTH.

Comment: I'm currently getting an error (Cannot find unit) when trying to use units, 99.99% sure its because the compiler doesn't know where to look for them. I've tried dropping the .ppu unit files into the project solution but it doesn't work, do you know how I can get units working?

Comment: The "Big 5" page can only be found in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20201127203746/https://pak.lebah.web.id/pascal5.html

Answer (score 4):

this is my tasks.json and it works very well

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "PAS build active file",
            "command": "fpc",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: All this does is compile the file. The OP was asking how to compile AND run the file.